# How to find in which container tree resides

Tags: jquery

I have dhtmlx tree. In one div i placed that tree. I have multiple divs and in each div I have one tree which will generate dynamically. When i click on the any node of tree i can get the id of that node. Now how to find in which div that tree resides by using jquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#id').closest('div')
```

Docs: http://api.jquery.com/closest/

Depending on the structure of your DOM you might need a different selector - but without you showing us the structure we can only make guesses.

Comment: Thanks Master... but when I put this in alert box it is showing as [object object]. How to see in text format?

Comment: Use `console.log()` and your browser's developer tools. `alert()` is not really suitable for debugging anyway.

Comment: @YSSS. `$('#id').closest('div').attr('id')`

Comment: BTW, why is your nickname _"ThiefMaster"_?

Comment: the first place i needed a nick was a forum about the thief2 game. and back to the topic: i'd use `.prop('id')`

Comment: @All, tree is generating dynamically. When I saw in the Developer tools tree nodes are not visible there and when i use the $('#id').closest('div').attr('id') it is giving as undefined

Answer (score 0):

If you are using tree's onClick event , you can use the next code to access container html node

```
tree.attachEvent("onClick", function(id){
    var node = this.parentObject; //html container of tree
});
```